# Work done through 2 different adiabatic processes

Tags: thermodynamics

Consider the equation of state $PV^\gamma=K$, where $K,\gamma$ are constants, $P$ is the pressure, and $V$ is the volume of a gas. The adiabatic work done on changing the volume from $V_1$ to $V_2=mV_1$, where $m$ is some real number, is
$$ W=-\int_{V_1}^{mV_1}KV^{-\gamma} dV = \frac{K}{\gamma -1}V_1^{1-\gamma}(m^{1-\gamma}-1).$$

Now consider a gas with volume $V_0$, where an adiabatic wall divides the gas in two portions with the same volume, and the whole system is bounded with adiabatic walls. If I remove the first adiabatic wall and go from $V_0$ to $V_0/10$ then the work will be
$$\frac{K}{\gamma -1}V_0^{1-\gamma}(0.1^{1-\gamma}-1).$$

If I start from the beginning and change the volume of each part from $V_0/2$ to $V_0/20$, then the work done in changing the volume of the two portions of gas is
$$2\frac{K}{\gamma -1}(V_0/2)^{1-\gamma}(0.1^{1-\gamma}-1).$$

Then I remove the adiabatic wall. The final volume of both procedures is the same, but the work in doing them is not the same!

Is this a correct result? If so, wouldn't the work have to be the same in both cases, given that the two paths are adiabatic?

Comment: Just a comment: $pV^{\gamma}$ is *not* an equation of state. It is a relation that holds when a system undergoes one of a particular class of quasi-static thermodynamic processes called *polytropic* processes. An equation of state is a relation between thermodynamic variables that *always* holds for a system in thermal equilibrium, even if it undergoing any quasi-static process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work is the same in both cases.  The K is not the same in the two cases.

Comment: Good eye. for case 1, $PV_0^\gamma=K_1$ and for case 2, $P (\frac {V_0}2)^\gamma=K_2$